# Quick Sort Implementation

Tags: c++

Hello all I am new to `C++` and have been diving into searching and sorting algorithms and decided to try writing my own. here are my prototypes:

```
void quicksort(int data[ ], size_t n);
// Precondition: data is an array with at least n components.
// Postcondition: The elements of data have been rearranged so
// that data[0] <= data[1] <= ... <= data[n-1].

void partition(int data[ ], size_t n, size_t& pivot_index);
// Precondition: n > 1, and data is an array (or subarray)
// with at least n elements.
// Postcondition: The function has selected some "pivot value"
// that occurs in data[0]..data[n-1]. The elements of data
// have then been rearranged, and the pivot index set so that:
//   -- data[pivot_index] is equal to the pivot;
//   -- Each item before data[pivot_index] is <= the pivot;
//   -- Each item after data[pivot_index] is > the pivot.

void setPivot(int data[ ], size_t n);
// Precondition: n > 1 and data is an array or subarray
// Postcondition: data[0] holds the selected pivot value
//  The original value of data[0] has been swapped with the selected pivot value
```

I have my `main` test written:

```
int main( )
{
    // Announce the program
    cout << "\nImplementing the QuickSort Algorithm\n";
    // Declare useful values
    const char BLANK = ' ';
    size_t i = 0;
    // Initialize our test data arrays
    const size_t SIZE1 = 10;
    int data1[]= {34, 33, 9, 45, 1, -1, 9, -18, 75, 100 };
    const size_t SIZE2 = 15;  // Number of elements in the array to be sorted
    int data2[]= {100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86 };
    const size_t SIZE3 = 1000;
    int data3[SIZE3];
    // Initialize the third array to random int values
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE3; i++)
        data3[i] = rand();
    // Beginning of quick sort tests
    // Sort the arrays and print the result with two blanks after each number
    quicksort(data1, SIZE1);
    cout << "\nSorted First Array: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
        cout << data1[i] << BLANK << BLANK;
    cout << endl;
    quicksort(data2, SIZE2);
    cout << "\nSorted Second Array: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE2; i++)
        cout << data2[i] << BLANK << BLANK;
    cout << endl;
    // On the large third array, just print the first ten and last ten values
    quicksort(data3, SIZE3);
    cout << "\nSorted Third Array (first ten): " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << data3[i] << BLANK << BLANK;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sorted Third Array (last ten): " << endl;
    for (i = SIZE3 - 10; i < SIZE3; i++)
        cout << data3[i] << BLANK << BLANK;
    cout << endl << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and I have started the function definitions:

```
void quicksort(int data[ ], size_t n)
// Library facilities used: cstdlib
{
    size_t pivot_index; // Array index for the pivot element
    size_t n1;          // Number of elements before the pivot element
    size_t n2;          // Number of elements after the pivot element

    if (n > 1)
    {
        // Partition the array, and set the pivot index.
        partition(data, n, pivot_index);

        // Compute the sizes of the subarrays.
        n1 = pivot_index;
        n2 = n - n1 - 1;

        // Recursive calls will now sort the subarrays.
        quicksort(data, n1);
        quicksort((data + pivot_index + 1), n2);
    }
}

void partition(int data[ ], size_t n, size_t& pivot_index)
// Library facilities used: algorithm, cstdlib
{
    assert(n > 1);
    setPivot(data, n);
}

void setPivot(int data[ ], size_t n)
// Library facilties used: algorithm, cstdlib
// This function chooses a pivot value as the median of three
// randomly selected values.  The selected pivot is swapped with
// data[0] so that the pivot value is in the first position of the array
{
    assert(n > 1);

}
```

my question is what would be the best way to finish `void partition(int data[], size_t n, size_t& pivot_index` and `void setPivot(int data[], size_t n)` in regards to speed?

Comment: Try `std::partition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a tricky question to answer and I like your jumping in with both feet. So when constructing a compiler you select instructions based off how many time units some instruction takes compared to another. Although you can use Raymond's advice and just use pre-constructed code you wouldn't learn much from that. The two most expensive instructions in a comparative sorting algorithm are the comparisons and the swaps in an array so you want to minimize those.

I'm going to first discuss the math behind a good partitioning algorithm. Let's assume that the pivot is in data[0] and consider the best way to minimize those expensive swaps. With the array ...

```
   [34, 33, 9, 45, 1, -1, 9, -18, 75, 100]
```

A good partitioning would minimize the number of times we move the pivot because we can't minimize the number of times we move something out of place around (We wouldn't be sorting if we could).

```
wall:=1
for(i:=1; i < n; ++i){
   if(data[0]>data[i]){
      swap(data, wall, i)
      ++wall
   }
}

swap(data, wall-1, 0)
pivot_index:=wall-1
```

So now to answer why is this one of the most efficient ways of doing it.

1. It minimizes the number of the expensive swaps
2. It minimizes the number of additions
3. The additions it does use, are ++ which will 100% translate to the INC %reg assembly instruction which is faster than adding 1 to a register which isn't guaranteed (... but most likely will). ((really really pedantic to do this))

Next a smart way of choosing the pivot. In the comment it says median but I'm going to change that to mean for statistical reasons and stick with the choose three random numbers. The runtime complexity of *Quick Sort* is all about the choice of pivot. Choose wrong and it could be O(n^2), choose right and it would approximate O(n*log(n)). The best choose of a pivot would be the number that evenly divides your array into two pieces of equal lengths. 50% of your datapoints are higher than the pivot, 50% are below, e.i. the mean. Calculating the mean of the population would be slow and ruin any performance we get if we have to calculate the mean ever step of the way so we'll only use a mean of a sample to estimate the mean of the population.

```
void setPivot(int data[ ], size_t n)

   index1:= rand_uniform()*n
   index2:= rand_uniform()*n
   index3:= rand_uniform()*n

   mean:=(data[index1]+data[index2]+data[index3])/3

   offset1:=abs(index1-mean)
   offset2:=abs(index2-mean)
   offset3:=abs(index3-mean)

   if(offset1 < offset2 && offset1 < offset3)
       swap(data,0,index1)
   else if(offset2 < offset1 && offset2 < offset3)
       swap(data,0,index2)
   else if(offset3 < offset1 && offset3 < offset2)
       swap(data,0,index3)
```

It should be clear that this has a lot of overhead doing it this way however the setPivot is in constant time complexity meaning for sufficiently large n it is faster doing it this way because the chosen piviot is statistically going to divide the data into two equal parts more often, which is the whole point of a good divide and conquer algorithm.

Comment: awesome! very informative! So would you say that for larger databases QuickSort would be the faster option? I know that depending on the way the data is originally sorted I.E. ascending to descending or at least somewhat in order then other sort methods are preferred? or should one only ever use Quicksort?

Comment: @AlexChapman Learning how different sorting algorithms work is great, but once you know how they work, one would generally just use the standard library to do this (i.e. `std::sort`).

Comment: I wouldn't say because *QuickSort* has O(n*log(n)) best time it is per se the best. It does have a good run time on average and this implementation with the smart pivot selection is highly improbably to run in worst case time of O(n^2). There is another sorting algorithm that takes advantage of a heap that always runs in O(n*log(n)) time fairly named *HeapSort* which is something you should definitely check out. If you want to get really optimal you can calculate for what size n *void partition* is faster than *void setPivot* and switch over to a naive pivot selection.

Comment: Awesome! thanks @kryler I appreciate all the information you've given!